# Losing session after file changed / uploaded

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-state

I am currently having a strange issue with sessions, I've worked with MVC for quite a while and never had this in previous versions. Currently making a new system using MVC5 for the first time, all is well. Sessions are being set with no issues, however, if I modify a cshtml file in VS my session is killed.

Also I have a file upload feature which works, but when you upload a file and then navigate to another page the session is gone again. This is working locally and also on a Windows Server box we use for sandboxing.

Has something changed with the new versions of MVC regarding sessions? I've never had this before. I've got it set to use in-proc sessions, never normally needed to change anything but I have for the sake of things used cookieless, used cookies etc as options. Nothing seems to work.

If anyone has an idea that would be great.

Comment: As for modification of `cshtml` files - IIS needs to re-compile the view and it should be no surprise that session is killed at that point, as (probably) the application pool is reset. What are the files you upload and where do they go? I've got many projects on latest MVC and no issues with files upload.

Comment: I think it is two of the same issue really. They are PDF files and they go in a folder inside the 'content' folder. It seems every time a file is modified/added/deleted/ etc it does a new compile. Though it never did this in MVC 4 and my code is pretty much exactly the same. Since when does MVC compile Views?

Comment: MVC always compiled views - on the first hit of a page it compiles views and caches the binary. You can deploy with views pre-compiled and you won't get the "first-hit penalty". The real question is "when did MVC start loosing session on view-compilation?" I'd guess that depends on session configuration - if you configure session data to be persisted outside of IIS, your session won't be killed on app-pool recycle.

Comment: So the cure would be to re-configure sessions. And not persist files into "Content" folder.

Comment: That I could understand, if it did the same in MVC 4 which it doesn't.

Comment: Trying changing the save location. Don't use website folder to save files. This might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is interesting that you haven't observed this earlier - as always when you update the contents of your web site, IIS could recompile declarative resources causing the restart of the app pool which effectively removes all session data stored in memory.

A solution would be to switch to other, persistent session storages, sql is possibly the easiest to configure. You just need a sql server where you run the script that creates the session database:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Another option would be to use the State Server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

The performance of the State Server is usually better than the SQl Server as the data is not persisted onto the disk. However, since the state server is a separate process, your application server won't loose sessions even when the app pool restarts.